# use of in Keyword IN keyword in Query

Tags: sql

select *
    from resource
    where ResourceID= 1 
      and ResourceKeyword in(gallery 1,1980)

I have an table called `resource`  with   columns  `ResourceID, ResourceKeyword`

`ResourceKeyword` can contain multiple values when ever I am using this query

I get an  syntax error

what is syntax to solve  it

thank  you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Random guess, string delimiters

```
select *
from resource
where ResourceID= 1 and ResourceKeyword in('gallery 1','1980')
```